# SQLite query to get count and specific number of rows

Tags: sqlite

I need to query a relatively large table for the number of rows that match a query, and then a subset of that.

For example, Find the number of rows where LastName starts with "smi", then select rows 11-20.

I feel like using `SELECT COUNT() FROM users WHERE LastName LIKE 'smi%'` and then following that with `SELECT * FROM users WHERE LastName LIKE 'smi%' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10` is inefficient because it runs the query twice, right?

Or is that the only way to do it.

Comment: that's the practice, yes

Comment: Thanks, that's all I was looking for!